# Resize the width of the UILabel exactly to the length of text in the label

Tags: swift, text, resize, alignment, uilabel

I am trying to resize the width of the UILabel exactly to the length of text in the label. I also want to print the current size of the label but not sure how, in this most recent version of Swift.

[image: uilabel not sized correctly]

```
func createTxt  (fontColor: UIColor , xco: CGFloat, yco: CGFloat, widthLength: CGFloat, heightLength: CGFloat, phrase : String, fontName: String, fontSize: CGFloat) {
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: xco, y: yco, width: widthLength, height: heightLength))
    label.textColor = fontColor
    label.font = UIFont(name: label.font.fontName, size: fontSize)
    label.textAlignment = .left
    label.text = phrase
    label.backgroundColor = .red
    self.view.addSubview(label)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to find the size of the label and set the frame manually you can use the `sizeThatFits(_:)` method.

Example:

```swift
let label = UILabel()
label.text = someLongText
label.frame = CGFrame(point: point, size: label.sizeThatFits(CGSize(
    width: CGFloat.infinity,
    height: yourStaticHeight
)))
```

Otherwise you could just use the `sizeToFit()` method, but you would need to set your layout constraints well for that to work.

Answer (score 0):

populate the label with its text and then:

```
label.sizeToFit()
```

You can then access its `.frame` property to get its `.size` and `.height`

Answer (score 0):

If you set UILabel with frame, you should use:

```
label.sizeToFit()
```

If you set UILabel in storyboard, only set its top, bottom and Horizontal Constraint.